# Register-PackageSource does not seem to work

Tags: powershell, nuget, myget

When I try to register a package source, it seems not to have any effect.

```
Get-PackageSource
```

produces the following output:

```
Name                             ProviderName     IsTrusted  Location
----                             ------------     ---------  --------
nuget.org                        NuGet            False      https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
nuget.org v2                     NuGet            False      https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/
EventStore                       NuGet            False      https://nuget.pkg.github.com/eventstore/index.json
Microsoft Visual Studio Offline… NuGet            False      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\
```

I then try to add a new source to a private MyGet feed:

```
Register-PackageSource -Name "CaaS MyGet" -Location "https://www.myget.org/F/redacted/api/v3/index.json" -ProviderName "NuGet" -Trusted
```

The command completes without error (there is no output at all).

Running `Get-PackageSource` again produces the exact same output as it did prior to running `Register-PackageSource`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that `Register-PackageSource` silently fails when using a v3 uri but works with a v2 uri.

Works:

[https://www.myget.org/F/[FEED]/auth/[API_KEY]/api/v2](https://www.myget.org/F/%5BFEED%5D/auth/%5BAPI_KEY%5D/api/v2)

Doesn't work:

[https://www.myget.org/F/[FEED]/auth/[API_KEY]/api/v3/index.json](https://www.myget.org/F/%5BFEED%5D/auth/%5BAPI_KEY%5D/api/v3/index.json)

Comment: What version of the PackageManagement module?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. You could approximate the version by comparing the date of this post to the release schedule of the module. I always aimed to keep everything up to date.